# Are the D2L XML formats published anywhere?

Tags: xml, desire2learn

I would like to be able to export my quizzes, to csv or xml or what have you..
Process them for my own database...and be able to reimport.

I can't seem to find out to export into csv format...and I can't find the xml schema of quiz questions.

Is this published anywhere?

Thank you,
 Mike

Answer (score 1):

Note that Desire2Learn does not have a published XML schema for the XML data formats for exported quizzes. One workaround for this is by inference: create an object of the you'd like to handle in serialized form, export it, and then use the exported form to derive a schema for others of the same type.

Note that the formats for exported XML objects from D2L have changed only very slowly over the years, and the expectation was that all such changes would have been additive in nature.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your quizzes using the Import/Export/Copy Components tool, which generates a Zip file leveraging the IMS CP and QTI formats (http://www.imsglobal.org/question/) as a baseline, with some custom D2L fields thrown in.  The resulting output may be a little daunting, but you can additionally import in the same format, and this format (unlike our CSV supported format) maintains the categories/sections of questions.

As an alternative, you can import in CSV.  The format for that is available as a sample from the Question Library.  Choose Import -> Import Source:  'From a Desire2Learn Text Format File' and a link to sample is provided.

An additional tool you may be interested in is the Question Importer Tool (https://academictech.doit.wisc.edu/help/learnuw-quiz-importer) which generates the CSV format, and provides an alternative authoring environment.

If you are looking to export your quiz results, that's available from Statistics, and there is an option to export results via CSV from there.